# Converting Chainlink oracle response (int256) to uint256

Tags: solidity, hardhat, chainlink, uint256

I am trying to get the latest ETH price from the Chainlink priceFeed contract. The response shows up like this **171617306235** as a BigNumber. So there is a couple of issues for me to be solved.

1 - My local variables are uint256. How can I assign the Chainlink response ( int256 ) to a uint256 variable?

2 - As evident, some calculations need to be done on the Chainlink response to make it a human-readable ETH price. How can I achieve this goal? For instance, how I should read something like **$1716.17** as the Ethereum price within my JS or Typescript file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Ali's answer

- the decimals in a price feed's answer can be obtained programmatically as part of the API response [reference](https://docs.chain.link/docs/price-feeds-api-reference/#functions-in-aggregatorv3interface)
- the number of decimals can also be manually from the [contract addresses reference page](https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses/) .... just click on "Show More Details" next to the relevant network.

If you're getting data from the Chainlink API and the API returns int256 for the `answer` (i.e. price see [reference](https://docs.chain.link/docs/price-feeds-api-reference/#latestrounddata)) , maybe you should change your local variables to int256.  Or you can try and use one of [these sorts of libraries](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/utils#SafeCast) to safely to convert to uint256.

The question is whether you really need the price data to be a uint  -- and if so cast/convert later rather than at the API fetching stage.

Answer (score 1):

The returned price from chainlink data feeds contains 8 additional digits along with the price for example `1716 17306235`

If you only want to price and not the additional digits then

```
uint256 price = uint256(171617306235) / 100000000;
```

This will return you **1716**

And if you want also eight digits after the price you can get like this

```
uint256 eightDigits = 171617306235 % 100000000;
```

It will return you **17306235**

And if you want only two digits after price as you mentioned in the question, then

```
uint256 twoDigits = eightDigits / 1000000;
```

it will give you *17*

After that, you can combine them and get your desired results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but uint256 cannot be assigned to a int256!

Comment: Chainlink response is a int256 and your variable is uint256.

Comment: This is called type casting, I use this in my projects so you can also.